# Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'waqas' codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to create a `database` using `CodeIgniter`. I have written this code.

```
 $template = 'application/views/install/db/dbwrite.php';
 $template_path =  set_realpath($template);
 $output_path   = 'application/config/database.php';
 $database_file = file_get_contents($template_path);
 $new  = str_replace("%HOSTNAME%",$_POST['dbhost'],$database_file);
 $new  = str_replace("%USERNAME%",$_POST['username'],$new);
 $new  = str_replace("%PASSWORD%",$_POST['password'],$new);
 $new  = str_replace("%DATABASE%",$_POST['dbname'],$new);
 $dbName = $_POST['dbname'];
 $sql = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $dbName";
 $this->db->query($sql);
 $handle = fopen($output_path,'w+');
 fwrite($handle,$new);
```

here the value of `$_POST['username']` is `root` and `$_POST['password']` is `''`. but the `$sql = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $dbName";` it gives me that error. and also mysql default `username` is `root` and `password` is `''`.

```
Error Number: 1044

Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'waqas'

CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS waqas

Filename: D:/xampp/htdocs/ci_api/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691
```

Comment: You need to access the database with a user. The `''` in `''@'localhost'` indicates that there is no user set. You'll probably need to set a password too before executing your query

Comment: @Misantorp I have updated my question. please review it.

Comment: Please include content of files you refer in your code that's not part of the `CodeIgniter` library. Two debugging suggestions; 1) hard code any variable that you're getting from `POST` or `str_replace'-ing` (ie `$db['dbname']['username'] = "root";`). After you get it to work 2) `var_dump($new)` and `var_dump($dbName)` to ensure that it's identical to what worked in 1)

Comment: You would also never want this to go public as you should never use $_POST in the way you are. Database usernames and passwords should be hardcoded absolutely.